# How to configure log4j2 to log `MyException` errors with WARN level

Tags: java, rx-java, log4j2, vert.x

How to configure log4j (v 2) to log `MyException` errors with WARN level?

See code (`rxjava`) example that throws the MyException exception

```
 return map.get(id).toObservable()
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .switchIfEmpty(Observable.error(new MyException("Happens")))
                .toSingle();
```

That is caught by log4j configuration and ends up with `ERROR` level for now.

Comment: catch this exception and log it yourself with `logger.warn()`?

Comment: If you throw an exception and don't catch it, it will probably stop the execution of the program and cause an Error. You need to catch the exception and log it using a `logger.warn(Exception e)` as suggested by Sergei. If you need the execution to stop as before, then you can throw the exception again after logging it.

Comment: the idea is: I wanted to avoid using explicit logic of log.error or log.warn out of the rx-flow, instead defining the hierarchy of exceptions to be configurable in the logj4 or somewhere to map what  exceptions to log level separately

Answer (score 0):

For reference I'm including the info you provided in your comment:

> I wanted to avoid using explicit logic of log.error or log.warn out of the rx-flow, instead defining the hierarchy of exceptions to be configurable in the logj4 or somewhere to map what exceptions to log level separately

Here's a very quick example of how you could do this:

```
package example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.logging.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class SomeClass {

    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getLogger();

    //Quick and dirty way to generate a map of exceptions to their log levels. Replace this with whatever method of configuration you prefer.
    public static Map<String,String> getExceptionLvlMap(){
        Map<String,String> exceptionToLvlMap = new HashMap<>();
        exceptionToLvlMap.put("java.io.IOException", "WARN");
        exceptionToLvlMap.put("java.lang.NullPointerException", "FATAL");
        return exceptionToLvlMap;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Map<String, String> lvlMap = getExceptionLvlMap();

        try {
            someOperation();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.log(Level.getLevel(lvlMap.get(e.getClass().getName())), "Something bad happened!", e);
        }

        try{
            anotherOperation();
        }catch(Throwable t){
            log.log(Level.getLevel(lvlMap.get(t.getClass().getName())), "Something crazy happened!", t);
        }
    }

    public static void someOperation() throws IOException{
        throw new IOException("It's an IOException!");
    }

    public static void anotherOperation(){
        String x = null;
        //Generate a NPE
        x.equals("foo");
    }
}
```

**log4j2.xml config file**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="WARN">
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n" />
        </Console>


    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

**Output**:

```
23:24:50.217 [main] WARN  example.SomeClass - Something bad happened!
java.io.IOException: It's an IOException!
    at example.SomeClass.someOperation(SomeClass.java:40) ~[classes/:?]
    at example.SomeClass.main(SomeClass.java:27) [classes/:?]
23:24:50.221 [main] FATAL example.SomeClass - Something crazy happened!
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at example.SomeClass.anotherOperation(SomeClass.java:45) ~[classes/:?]
    at example.SomeClass.main(SomeClass.java:33) [classes/:?]
```